# Is there an R function that can calculate the Integrated biomarker response (IBR) index?

Tags: r, function

Please can somebody help me with this, BENOIT BELIAEFF and THIERRY BURGEOT (2002) created the INTEGRATED BIOMARKER RESPONSE (IBR), however I did not find any tool for R that would help in this calculation, does anyone know any?

Comment: The paper (https://doi.org/10.1002/etc.5620210629) says " The EXCEL software (Microsoft, Redmond, WA, USA) was used for all calculations and star plots. "  The computations look pretty simple. Can you have a go at writing code to compute them yourself, then ask for help when you get stuck? Alternatively, you could try the `r-sig-eco@r-project.org` mailing list:  package requests are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: You may also try asking this question in the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that actually that index was revisited by Devin et al. 2014 (DOI 10.1007/s11356-013-2169-9)? Try looking into it when you can!

But, about the R package: I was also having troubles finding one that actually does this type of calculation, and what I found was this new package called `IBRtools`

https://github.com/ecologicaltools/IBRtools

It contains a function called `ibr_index` that gives you a list of the index values and also the mean of the index values.

Furthermore, it also provides a function to graph your results, called `ibr_chart`, that creates a radarchart based on standardized values created by function `ibr_std`

I would definitely recommend looking into the package help section for further clarifications!